# How to get rid of extra numbered blank page before cover page in LyX?

Tags: lyx, external-files, covers

I have a 50 pages document in LyX. For this report I have to add a coverpage before the title with different style and template from the report. This is what I do:
I create my coverpage in a separate LyX file and compile it to "cover_page.pdf"
At the beginning of my report I insert an "External Material, PDFPages" and put the "cover_page.pdf" there.
in LaTeX and LyX options tab I write "pages=-" (Although I am not sure what it does! I suppose if the external material is has multiple pages, without this command just the first page is shown)

When I compile the whole thing, My cover page is there before the title but the output PDF file starts with an extra blank page that is numbered (1) also.

Is there a way to get rid of this page?
Thanks,

P.S. Someone has suggested somewhere that the paragraph settings should be on "Default". Mine is on default but still I have this problem.

EDIT: I tried the same coverpage with a minimal example, a containing just a title. This is the exported LaTex:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% A simple dot to overcome graphicx limitations
\newcommand{\lyxdot}{.}
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{\includepdf[pages=-]{Candidature_Coverpage}Title}\maketitle
\end{document}
```

But the blank page is still there before the coverpage.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Indeed, with `pages=-` all the pages in the PDF will be included.  So the blank page is before the cover page? Can you create a minimal document showing the behaviour (see http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample) and edit your post to include this `.lyx` file, or exported LaTeX code?

Comment: Thanks, that made it really easy to see where the problem was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you've inserted the cover page as part of the title, it should be before the title, and the style should be *Standard*. To fix this, place the cursor between the included PDF and the title, and hit enter to add a paragraph break between them. Then move the cursor to the paragraph containing the inserted PDF, and select *Standard* from the style drop-down menu in the top left.

Comment: @Adham Glad I could help. You could consider accepting my answer, to mark the question as solved, by clicking the checkmark on the left.